# Not able to show git user id ,follower,photo in Angular HTML page

Tags: angular

Problem statement-
I am working with typescript and my task is i have a component with a textbox and a button. in the textbox i need to pass a git username and press the button. On click of the button i want to fetch that particular user details(id,follower,photo) in a textbox.

Tried-
i have made a component and a service and with the service i am able to hit the api and successfully get the use detals in json format but my concern is how to print the partcular id ,follower and phot in different textboxes . for that i saved that output in a array but not able to print in html.

component.html

```
Enter Username: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username" />
<button (click)="searchUserDetails()">Search User</button>>
</div>>
<div >
    <table>
        <tr>
            User ID:<input type="text" [value]= />
        </tr>>
        <tr>
            Followers:<input type="text" name="followers" />
        </tr>>
    </table>  
</div>>
```

component.ts

```
import { GituserdetailsService } from '../service/gituserdetails.service';
import { JsonPipe } from '@angular/common';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-userdetails',
  templateUrl: './userdetails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userdetails.component.css']
})
export class UserdetailsComponent implements OnInit {
username:string ;
details:any=[];
  constructor(private GituserdetailsService:GituserdetailsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    //this.searchUserDetails();

  }
searchUserDetails() :void{
  this.details = [];
  this.GituserdetailsService.searchUser(this.username).subscribe((data: any[])=>{
    console.log(data);
    this.details = data;
  })  ;
  //console.log(this.username);
}
}
```

service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GituserdetailsService {
   username:String;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

    searchUser(username:String) :Observable<any>
   {
     console.log(`http://api.github.com/users/`+username);
    return this.http.get(`http://api.github.com/users/`+username)

}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned data is not array, so take a variable of type any and store your output in that variable

See the below code :

```
mydata : any; 

getUser(username) {
   this.http.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${username}`).subscribe((data)=>{
    this.mydata = data; 
    console.log(this.mydata); 
   }); 
}
```

To display text data in HTML you can use code as below

```
<p> {{ this.mydata.login }} </p>
```

To display image in HTML you can use code as below

```
<img src="{{this.mydata.avatar_url}}" width="300">
```